# Loop though excel to check for text

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel in below format:

[image]

I want a formula to loop through each row and identify if there is fail in any row. So result should be something line below. I can do this in VBA but wanted to check if we can do this using excel formula.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `E1`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,D1)=COUNTIFS(A:A,D1,B:B,"Pass"),"Pass","Fail")
```

**Edit :**

In `D1` copied down  :

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(FREQUENCY($A$1:$A$10,$A$1:$A$10),$A$1:$A$10),ROW(A1)),"")
```

Or, use "Remove Duplicates" Excel built-in function

[image]

Comment: is there a way the formula can list column D as well so that I don't have to hardcode that